# How to rotate the curve

Tags: plotting

How can I rotate this curve[image]

It's supposed to be like this

[image]

UPDATE:

[image]

I would like to show the "Blue" curve instead of the "Red" Curve. Even though I changed the equation in wolfram, the place of the curve did not move.

Comment: If you really want to rotate everything, you can do `Rotate[Plot[…], 90°]`

Comment: I'm sorry, I just want to rotate the curve

Comment: Then something like `ParametricPlot[{Sin[x],x},{x,0,10}]`?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Can the downvoters at least leave a comment so the author of the OP can benefit from that and ask questions better in the future? I am upvoting just because

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

In [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) you just interchange the coordinates. Both shown for comparison.

```
ParametricPlot[
 {{t, Sqrt[10 + t^2]}, {Sqrt[10 + t^2], t}},
 {t, -20, 30},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   {HoldForm[y == Sqrt[10 + x^2]],
    HoldForm[x == Sqrt[10 + y^2]]},
   {.6, .9}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Using `ReflectionTransform`:**

```
Clear[f, g, x, y]
f[x_] := Sqrt[x^2 + 10]
g[x_] := Sqrt[x^2 + 50]
p1 = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -10, 10}];
Show[p1, Plot[x, {x, -15, 15}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}], 
 p1 /. L_Line :> {GeometricTransformation[L, 
     ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
 ]
```

[image]

---

**Using `ContourPlot`:**

```
ContourPlot[
 {y == f[x], x == f[y]} // Evaluate
 , {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesStyle -> Dashed
 ]
```

[image]

To get both curves:

```
ContourPlot[
 {{y == f[x], y == g[x]}, {x == f[y], x == g[y]}} // Evaluate
 , {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}
 , ContourStyle -> {ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2]}
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesStyle -> Dashed
 ]
```

Comment: By total chance I was on the `ReflectionTransform` doc page and then this question popped up.

Comment: [In your ReflectionTransform plot] Is there a possible way to remove the upper curves and just show the curves on the right-side of the graph?

Comment: In the `Show` command, don't include `p1`.  The `Show` command is showing three entities; the original plot, the dashed lines and the transformed plot. Use as required.

Comment: Ahh thanks I got it! How about the dashed line?

Comment: `Show[p1 /. L_Line :> {GeometricTransformation[L, 
     ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Export[
    "Test.GIF",
    With[
        {
            f=Function[{x}, Sqrt[10+x^2]]
        },
        Animate[
            ParametricPlot[
                RotationTransform[angle][{f[x],x}]
                , {x, -10,10}
                , AspectRatio -> 1
                , PlotRange -> {{-10,10}, {-10,10}}
            ]
            , {angle, 0, 2Pi, Pi/16}
        ]
    ]
]
```

[image]